# why the acl just update the current node in redis cluster when i use ACL SAVE and ACL LOAD?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I create a redis cluster and try to use acl.
I want to make some user can aceess the special prefix.

But when i use `acl load` or `acl save`, it just save in the current node.

May I update users in ervery nodes by the redis-cli ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redis cluster **does not** propagate configuration between its nodes automatically (as you've noted). This applies both to regular (redis.conf) and user (ACL) configuration directives.

You need to copy the ACL files to all nodes, or issue the same [`ACL SETUSER`](https://redis.io/commands/acl-setuser) commands on each node.